# Why doesn't my result string print to the logcat after parsing json data?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a Json feed from wunderground.com and display the result in the logcat but nothing prints when it gets to the Log.v statement. I know call is going through because it shows up on the analitics page on wunderground. I'm using Android Studio and I'm not getting any errors or crashes. It just doesn't print. And if its because the result string is null why does it not have the json data in it? Please help. Thanks.

this is my AsyncTask class:

```
class MySubAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        String result;

        Log.d("TEST", "parse is working");

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYAPIKEYHERE/forecast/geolookup/astronomy/q/FL/Tampa.json");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                theStringBuilder.append(line);
                theStringBuilder.append("\n");
            }

            result = theStringBuilder.toString();

            Log.v("TEST","Full JSON string = ");
            Log.v("TEST", result);

            return result;


        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.d("TEST","IO Error 1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("TEST","IO Error 2");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("TEST","IO Error 3");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("TEST", "Log after finally");

        return null;
    }

}
```

The only output i get in the logcat is the first two Log statements:

04-19 22:23:03.022 2411-2948/com.eli.myweatherapp D/TEST: parse is working

04-19 22:23:03.825 2411-2948/com.eli.myweatherapp V/TEST: Full JSON string =

The log statement with my result string and the log staement after the finally block both don't print and i have no idea why.

edit:
i added this code before connection.getInuptStream()

```
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(connection.getResponseCode())
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(connection.getResponseMessage())
                    .append("\n");

            Map<String, List<String>> map = connection.getHeaderFields();
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
            {
                if (entry.getKey() == null)
                    continue;
                builder.append( entry.getKey())
                        .append(": ");

                List<String> headerValues = entry.getValue();
                Iterator<String> it = headerValues.iterator();
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    builder.append(it.next());

                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        builder.append(", ")
                                .append(it.next());
                    }
                }

                builder.append("\n");
            }

            Log.d("TEST",builder.toString());
```

now it prints this to the logcat:

04-20 20:19:10.364 14680-15085/com.eli.myweatherapp D/TEST: 200 OK

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
                                                                     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                                                                     Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
                                                                     Connection: keep-alive
                                                                     Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
                                                                     Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:19:10 GMT
                                                                     Expires: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:19:10 GMT
                                                                     Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:19:10 GMT
                                                                     Pragma: no-cache
                                                                     Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
                                                                     Set-Cookie: DT=1461197950:16390:365-u3; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com, Prefs=FAVS:1|WXSN:1|PWSOBS:1|WPHO:1|PHOT:1|RADC:0|RADALL:0|HIST0:NULL|GIFT:1|PHOTOTHUMBS:50|EXPFCT:1|; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com
                                                                     Vary: Accept-Encoding
                                                                     X-Android-Received-Millis: 1461197950363
                                                                     X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
                                                                     X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1461197949971
                                                                     X-CreationTime: 0.102

Comment: did you check if you are reciving any data from the server? Because theStringBuilder.toString() is not showing beacause is empty.

Comment: when i paste the url into a browser the json feed comes up and the site shows I'm making calls in the statistics. is ther another way to check fo se if i am recieving data?

Comment: yes, use a debugger to see that the String actually containts value

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. how do i do that?

Comment: @BusterDublup here is the official guide on using the debugger. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: @BusterDublup I was hoping that would show a Content-Length, but it doesn't.  That really indicates that the server actually isn't sending any data.

Comment: so is that because of something I've written incorrectly or because of something on the server side?

Comment: @BusterDublup I can't tell at this point.  You can try making requests to other sites, like google.com or others, just to see if you get reponses from them.

Answer (score 0):

The logger will not print the line if the value is empty.

So the specific reason that `Log.v("TEST", result);` is not printing anything, is because `result` is an empty string.

You can add log statements to show the size to see this as well.

I tested this just by running:

```
Log.v("TEST","111");
Log.v("TEST","");
Log.v("TEST","333");
```

You are probably not getting any logs after the `finally`, because you are already returning inside the `try` block.

I can also see that your code would not compile: you have no semicolon after `getInputStream`.

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Are you sure this is the actual code you have in your app?

Comment: thanks, but why is the string null then? it should have all the json data in it.

Comment: @BusterDublup see my update about the typo on getInputStream - is this the whole code you have?

Comment: sorry. yes it is the code I'm using. i think that semicolon got delete when i was deleting my comments from the code. i added it back in now.

Comment: @BusterDublup before calling getinputstream, can you add the logging from the answer in this post. stackoverflow.com/q/20976013/4674122. The http response code, headers, etc..

Comment: it printed: 04-20 20:08:19.358 32659-676/com.eli.myweatherapp D/TEST: 200 OK    is that what youre looking for?

Comment: @BusterDublup Can you add that log output of the 200 OK and all of the headers to your initial post, that might help someone identify why your response has no data.  I think printing the headers may be more useful

Comment: thank you. i think i added what you are talking about.